# Problem perform Drag and Drop javascript "The provided float value is non-finite" - BPMN

Tags: javascript, bpmn

I am trying to perform a drag and drop on this website: https://demo.bpmn.io/new

In order to do that I am using the following javascript code:

```
var dataTransfer=
            {
                dropEffect:'',
                effectAllowed:'all',
                files:[],
                items:{},
                types:[],
                setData:function(format,data)
                {
                    this.items[format]=data;
                    this.types.append(format);
                },
                getData:function(format)
                {
                    return this.items[format];
                },
                clearData:function(format){}
            };
var emit=function(event,target)
                {
                    var evt=document.createEvent('Event');
                    evt.initEvent(event,true,false);
                    evt.dataTransfer=dataTransfer;
                    target.dispatchEvent(evt);
                };

function getElementByXpath(path) {return document.evaluate(path, document, null, XPathResult.FIRST_ORDERED_NODE_TYPE, null).singleNodeValue;}; 

var DragNDrop=function(src,tgt) {
    src = getElementByXpath(src);
    tgt = getElementByXpath(tgt);
    emit('dragstart',src);
    emit('dragenter',tgt);
    emit('dragover',tgt);
    //Errors start from here
    emit('drop',tgt);
    emit('dragend',src);
    return true;
}
```

The code should be correct, as it works when I use it to perform a drag and drop in this website:  https://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop

The problem is that when I use it on a bpmn example (https://demo.bpmn.io/new) it does not work. Here is the command used and its relative errors:

Command:

```
DragNDrop('//*[@class="entry bpmn-icon-intermediate-event-none"]', '(//*[starts-with(@data-element-id,"Lane")])[1]');
```

Errors:

- TouchInteractionEvents.js:262 Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'elementFromPoint' on 'Document': The provided double value is non-finite.
- EventBus.js:377 TypeError: Failed to execute 'setTranslate' on 'SVGTransform': The provided float value is non-finite.
- Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'setTranslate' on 'SVGTransform': The provided float value is non-finite.